# Projection of measure zero set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a set of measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $E_x,E_y$ be the projection of E on the $x$-axis and $y$-axis respectively.

Is it true that atleast one of $E_x$ and $E_y$ is measurable and measure zero in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Let $N$ be a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and define $E = \{(x,x) : x \in N\}$. Then $E$ has zero Lebesgue outer-measure, and so, it is Lebesgue-measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But obviously $E_x=E_y=N$ is non-measurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider the set $E=\{(x,y):x=y\}$. This set has measure $0$ but its projections are measurable and do not.